# Deciding whether to create new collection or put data in existing collection using Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, collections, standards, database

I have data coming in from two sources, facebook and twitter. For each source I have multiple handles (pepsi, coke, sprite) and I want to determine the best way to organize my database.

Is it better practice to...

a. make two collections, one for twitter and one for facebook and have all all three handles in both collections?

b. make one collection and put all of that information in that single collection?

Thanks for your help. Mongodb is awesome.

Comment: It depends on what you plan on doing with the data.  If you're going to want data from twitter and facebook at the same time, then put them together.  I don't see the benefit of keeping them separate.

Comment: For the meantime, the data will likely be exported into csv. There will probably be one csv that has the facebook data and one csv that has the twitter data. Eventually, I want to put the data in a nice GUI so people can look at the data in a table format. The information can't fit all in one table or csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on many factors really, but generally speaking...

If the data is somewhat similar and/or should be queried (aggregated) together then single collection is probably the best choice.

If the data from twitter and fb should be processed in totally different ways then perhaps separated collections is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up doing both a and b for two different data sets. I was looking at multiple brands and the problem was that some brands had twitter handles and didn't have facebook handles and visa versa. So I decided to separate them into two different collections. However, when I started recording both the twitter and facebook data for one brand, I decided to put it into a single collection. Having everything consolidated in a single collection is definitely the better way to go if possible.